# We randomly paint each side of a fair coin black or white. What is the probability that..

Tags: probability

We have a fair coin and we randomly and independently paint each side either white or black. Then we flip the coin twice and we get a white side two times.
Given that result, what is the probability that:
1) Both sides of the coin are white?
2) The coin landed on the same side twice in a row?

So we have 4 probabilities of coloring - WW, WB, BW, BB (W = white, B = black).
I denoted the following events:
A - the coin was flipped twice and we got a white side two times (what we know)
B - both sides of the coin are white
C - the coin landed on the same side twice

I have managed to solve (1) by using the conditional probability theorem:

$P(B | A) = \frac{P( B \cap A)} { P(A) } $
USing the law of total probability and considering each possible coloring with an equal probability of $ \frac{1}{4} $ to get that coloring, I got that $ P(A) = \frac{3}{8} $
Using the chain rule, we know that $ P(B \cap A) = P(A|B) * P(B) = 1 * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} $

( In retrospect I just used Bayes theorem explicitly)

So the final answer for (1) is $ \frac{2}{3} $.

How ever, when I try the second part, I end up with the same result for each calculation, and I tried to list of possible scenarios using a binary tree, but I got lost on the way. Is there any trick to the second part or Im just lacking some confidence in my logic?

EDIT:
Forgot to add my calculations..

So I need to caclulate $ P(C|A) $.
I already calculated $ P(A) = \frac{3}{8} $.
Now I need to calculate $ P(C \cap A)$, that is the probability of both events A and C, i.e. the coin landed and the same side and the side was painted white.
Using the law of total probabillity:

$ P(C \cap A) = P(C \cap A | WW coloring) * P(WW coloring) + P(C \cap A | WB coloring) * P(WB coloring) + P(C \cap A | BW coloring) * P(BW coloring) + P(C \cap A | BB coloring) * P(BB coloring) = (\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2}) * \frac{1}{4} + (\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2}) * \frac{1}{4} + (\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2}) * \frac{1}{4} + 0 * \frac{1}{4} = frac{4}{16} = \frac{1}{4}$

Thus the result ends up $\frac{2}{3}$ again.

Comment: What do you mean by "end up with the same result for each calculation"? Can you include your attempt at (2)? Your attempt at (1) looks fine, by the way.

Comment: @MeesdeVries my bad! forgot to copy that part from my lyx solution

Comment: Your solution for $2)$ appears to be right as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event $B$ and $C$ are not mutually exclusive : the coin could land on the same side twice, while having both sides painted white. So you don't need to have $P(B\mid A)+P(C\mid A)\leq 1$.

Using the same argument as the firt question:
$$ P(C\mid A) = \frac{P(A\mid C)P(C)}{P(A)}$$
And using $P(C)=1/2$, $P(A\mid C)= 1/2$, and $P(A)=3/8$, we end up with 
$$ P(C\mid A) =\frac{2}{3}$$